# Postgres perform aggregation on array or string_agg

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, csv, case

I have a column which is a string of comma seperated elements like this `statuses= 'Initial,Initial,Completed,InProgress`. And I what to make a status column like this:

```
CASE
    WHEN <all statuses are 'Initial'> THEN 'Initial'
    WHEN <all statuses are 'Completed'> THEN 'Completed'
    ELSE 'InProgress'
END AS status
```

I have tried `bool_and(string_to_array(statuses,',')='Initial')`, which does not compile. Any suguestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with `string_to_array()` and the `ALL` operator:

```
case 
    when 'Initial'   = ALL(string_to_array(statuses, ',')) then 'Initial'
    when 'Completed' = ALL(string_to_array(statuses, ',')) then 'Completed'
    else 'InProgress'
end status
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c2555036aebbda8fed9cd2b37f237103)**:

```
with t as (
    select 'Initial,Initial' statuses
    union all select 'Completed,Completed'
    union all select 'Initial,Completed,Other'
)
select 
    statuses,
    case 
        when 'Initial'   = ALL(string_to_array(statuses, ',')) then 'Initial'
        when 'Completed' = ALL(string_to_array(statuses, ',')) then 'Completed'
        else 'InProgress'
    end status
from t
```

```
statuses                | status    
:---------------------- | :---------
Initial,Initial         | Initial   
Completed,Completed     | Completed 
Initial,Completed,Other | InProgress
```